# Any suggestions/recommendations to improve Elasticsearch search speed?

Tags: elasticsearch

I have an Elasticsearch cluster of 1 replica, 2 nodes, and in total 2 shards. One of my indexes calls 'products' is massive and it contains around 7 million records and it costs around 56GB. So we are planning to split the index into 5 shards for each replica(a total of 10 shards) to increase search speed.
I'm looking for the perfect amount of shards for the replicas as a suggestion to try out and any other recommendations/tips to increase the search speed for this infrastructure.

Also, there's a multi-search query that is slower than others. Hoping for some good suggestions/tips for that too.

Thank you!

Comment: Have you taken a lokk at this https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/tune-for-search-speed.html

Comment: 5 shards / replica should be better for 56go. Note the more shards you have, the more indexation / update will be long. Share the multisearch query if you can, do you use _source filtering, do you use filter inside query if you dont need score? Is your mapping optimized ( => keywors...)

Answer (score 1):

generally speaking - fewer shards are better for reading (ie searching), more are better for indexing

a 56 gig index in Elasticsearch is not that big, but then it's all relative to your use case. I am not sure that increasing the shard count is worth it here without understanding your use case and setup

your best bet would be to use Elasticsearch Rally to do some testing with your data and your queries and then figure out what configuration works the best for your use case - https://esrally.readthedocs.io/en/stable/